# Print Spooler Service Unexpectedly Terminated

Tags: windows-7, print-spooler

On my 64bit laptop, the print spooler service has been terminating unexpectedly (Microsoft's words) for the past day.  I've looked at the event log and it just tells me happened, not why.  Are there some things I can do to help me discover why it has failed?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs to see if there are any commonalities between the system messages around when the service has terminated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up restarting the computer twice, and the service has been on since.  Not sure what was causing it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest versions of your printer's drivers, you've installed any critical Window's updates.

Also, check the system logs for any messages that are the same right around when the service has been terminating. Similar messages can indicate possible causes of failure.